# How to do multi-pick-point color selection in the Advanced Color Editor of Capture One?

Tags: capture-one

The blog posting [How to do radical color changes in your images](https://blog.phaseone.com/how-to-do-radical-color-changes-in-your-images/) for Capture One uses a technique where multiple colours are picked to make big hue adjustments. It has the following image:

[image]

Notice how multiple pick points are shown at the same time. I'm not sure what I'm looking at here because I can't make Capture One do the same thing. Are these multiple, separate color picks where the pick points should "work together", or are they separate and the image has just been photoshopped to make multiple picks evident? When I try to do this in Capture One 11, I end up with multiple picks where the pick points and surrounding area are displayed separately.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it even makes a difference - perhaps this was simply the way that e.g. C1 v7 showed the selected color area. (It would seem this way, as ["Nail down exact color correction"](https://blog.phaseone.com/nail-down-exact-color-correction/) shows the same behavior.) The article does not mention him picking multiple points for one correction, and either way, the tool works just as in this example with only one point in C1 v11.

**The article's "multiple picks" refer to multiple corrections**, because in C1, you can only change the hue by ± 30° - e.g. to go from red to cyan, you need 6x +30° layers for the same object and the same color.